# function is callign but Ajax is not calling

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, highcharts

Here I am using codeigniter with highchart. Highchart will change after dropdown select by calling ajax.
Here, function is called but ajax is not calling. So, where I go wrong with this.

This is my ajax:

```
$('.edit').click(function(e) 
{ 
           e.preventDefault();
           $.ajax({    
                       url: '<?php echo site_url("Chart/branchwiseactivity");?>',
                       type: 'POST',
                       data: {
                                   series: []
                             },
                             dataType: 'json',
                             success: function(json) 
                             { 
                                  options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                                  options.series[0] = json[1];
                                  options.series[1] = json[2];
                                  options.series[2] = json[3];
                                  options.series[3] = json[4];
                                  chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                              }

                         });
                     e.preventDefault();
               });
```

Comment: Is this url `site_url("Chart/branchwiseactivity")` accessible?

Comment: Run a [console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) and observe what kind of errors you have